# Setting up Sticky Session on AWS ELB for Prestashop

Tags: session, cookies, amazon-web-services, prestashop-1.5

i am currently toying around with my shop hoping that i can load balance my shop.

I basically want to use the sticky session feature for my load balancer (see image below):

[image: Sticky Session Using Application Cookie]

Unfortunately i don't know what value should i put here. This is basically where i am stuck with. As far as i know, prestashop encrypt cookies information (both name and value).

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Cookie Information]

I have got a hunch that somehow i need to hard-code it in such a way that i creates a new cookie name and associated with a unique value for a particular session.

Can anyone help me with this? What should i do?

FYI: I am using Prestashop 1.5.4.x

Comment: do prestashop's instructions indicate you need to use your own cookie? If not, use the middle option.

Comment: @tedder42 i am not sure about that, i might as well try it then. The thing is that prestashop creates session cookies (and its content is encrypted). Which can be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the answer on the Internet, but I managed to solve the problem for the admin section of Prestashop. You should use the option of Sticky sessions in the ELB, as you can't name the cookie that Prestashop uses. Next, you should disable the option "Check the cookie's IP address" under Administration->Preferences, but might lead to security problems. Don't know how serious.

Comment: should i use Application Generated Cookies Stickiness on ELB AWS ?